# Variable calculation not working (jquery/javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

OK, maybe I'm just blind and missing something obvious, but this is the weirdest issue I've ever seen...

I have the following code:

```
var innerHeight;

$(function(){
    var contentTop = 116;  // calculated on the fly from page header
    var contentBottom = 37;  // calculated on the fly from page footer
    console.log('window.height'); 
    console.log($(window).height());
    console.log('contentTop'); 
    console.log(contentTop);
    console.log('contentBottom'); 
    console.log(contentBottom);

    console.log('$( window ).height() - contentTop - contentBottom');
    console.log((parseInt($( window ).height()) - parseInt(contentTop) - parseInt(contentBottom)));

    innerHeight = (parseInt($( window ).height()) - parseInt(contentTop) - parseInt(contentBottom));
    console.log('innerHeight'); 
    console.log(innerHeight);
});
```

It should spit out:

```
window.height
936
contentTop
116
contentBottom
37
$( window ).height() - contentTop - contentBottom
783
innerHeight
783
```

It does spit out:

```
window.height
936
contentTop
116
contentBottom
37
$( window ).height() - contentTop - contentBottom
783
innerHeight
936
```

Notice the last number.

I tried all kinds of variations to have `innerHeight` be the result of the formula `$( window ).height() - contentTop - contentBottom` - but it just fails...

I'm running Firefox Nightly (64bit) version 28.0a1.

In Chrome, I just notice that the result is off by maybe 8 or so, but haven't had time to look deeper because this Firefox issue is just blowing me away...

Any clue?

FYI, I have tried adding `parseInt()` around each of the three parts of the line in question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
Math.floor($( window ).height() - contentTop - contentBottom);
```

Comment: Please provide a more in-depth explanation of the problem with the original code. Otherwise, OP won't be able to learn anything from it.

Comment: Didn't work, either. I also already tried `parseInt()` on every entry separately...

Answer (score 0):

Duh - sleep deprivation really IS bad for you...

Obviously, `innerHeight` cannot be used as a variable - if I just write it, it implies `window.innerHeight`...

Changed the variable name, now it works.

Now I really wish I could withdraw the question...

Comment: That's why you should use `var` with the variables you use, so that they won't conflict with the global scope (you will never know which variables are defined and will be define in future in the gobal scope). Using tools like `jslint` or `jshint` will help you to detect such mistakes (not every time, but many of them)

Comment: Except I did use `var` - my first line of js code was `var innerHeight;`, then I started `$(function()` expecting the variable to be used as global. I just didn't pay attention to what I called it :-/

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to say that writing a `var` outside of a function _defines_ it in the global scope, so it does not make a real difference if it is there or not, if you adding something to it, it is still like writing `window.varName = ...`. At least for the browsers environment.